# TweepError : Bad Authentication data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tweepy

So I'm currently working on a project to create a twitter bot and I'm experiencing problems trying to run the following command in cmd:

`api.mentions_timeline()`

When I type API into the Python shell it returns with `<tweepy.api.API object at 0x0000015A0345A348>` which is the expected outcome.

I've only created one file that contains all my twitter api/tweepy keys:

```
import tweepy
ACCESS_TOKEN = "########"
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = "############"
CONSUMER_KEY = "#################"
CONSUMER_SECRET = "################"

# OAuth process, using the keys and tokens
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
# Creation of the actual interface, using authentication
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
# collect tweets on     #MRT
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="MRT",count=100,
                       lang="en",rpp=100).items():
    print (tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
```

From running the `api.mentions_timeline()` it returns the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 250, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 234, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 215, 'message': 'Bad Authentication data.'}]
>>>
```

The expected outcome should return some data.

Comment: How are you trying to run `api.mentions_timeline()`? This code snippet only shows `api.search`

Comment: here is how the full command in cmd looks like                                                       ```>>> api
<tweepy.api.API object at 0x0000015A0345A348>
>>> api.mentions_timeline()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 250, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 234, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 215, 'message': 'Bad Authentication data.'}]
>>>```

Comment: I still don't know how you're trying to call this script.

Answer (score 1):

Tweepy could not authenticate you. Try fill in the keys and secrets again with your unique codes.This is how I was able to solve this.